# Function to list elements that are lists

Tags: r

lets say I have a list in r that contains other lists and I want to remove certain characters (comma in the following example) from elements of each list.

```
my.list <- list(c("hello , world ", "hello world,,," ),c("123,456", "1,234"))
```

The following gets the job done

```
gsub(",", "", my.list[[1]])

gsub(",", "", my.list[[2]])
```

but how do I do it more efficiently as my actual problem is long?  I tried the following but it gives me strange results

```
lapply(my.list, function(x) gsub(",","",my.list))
```

any help?  thx

Comment: `lapply(my.list, function(x) gsub(",","", x))` ;)

Comment: I'd suggest editing your title and question a little, maybe something like "Edit strings in a list" for the title. When you say *list in r that contains other lists* it sounds like a list of lists, e.g., `list(list("hello, world", c("hello", "world")), list('123,456'))`. But your example data is a list of character vectors, not a list of lists. Much simpler.

Comment: That said, I'd also suggest closing as typo, because I think Moody_Mudskipper's comment is spot-on. You just wrote `my.list` where you needed `x` instead.

Comment: yes, it was simply replace my.list with x in the gsub function and it fixed it all.  Thanks Gregor and Moody_Mudskipper!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to utilize the function `filter_element`

I would suggest sanitizing your data before combining them into a list. Once the data has been sanitized, then start setting entering them into lists.

You can check out the documentation for `filter_element` on page 10 in the following PDF.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/textclean/textclean.pdf